# How to find the $\max|z|$ and $\min|z|$ for $|z+(4/z)|=2$?

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $z$ be a complex number that satisfies $|z+(4/z)|=2$ then find $\max|z|$ and $\min|z|$ .

I just need to know that how I should approach this problem.

Comment: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/ComplexNumberInequalities.shtml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The Maximum Modulus**

We have by the Triangle Inequality that
$$2=\left|z+\frac{4}{z}\right|\geq |z|-\frac{4}{|z|}\,.$$
Thus, 
$$|z|^2-2|z|-4\leq 0\,.$$
This means
$$-\sqrt{5}+1\leq |z|\leq \sqrt{5}+1\,.$$
Hence,
$$|z|\leq \sqrt{5}+1\,.$$
The equality holds iff $z=\pm(\sqrt5+1)\,\text{i}$.

---

**The Minimum Modulus**

We have by the Triangle Inequality that
$$2=\left|z+\frac{4}{z}\right|\geq \frac{4}{|z|}-|z|\,.$$
Thus, 
$$|z|^2+2|z|-4\geq 0\,.$$
This means
$$|z|\geq \sqrt{5}-1\text{ or }|z|\leq -\sqrt{5}-1\,.$$
Hence,
$$|z|\geq \sqrt{5}-1\,.$$
The equality holds iff $z=\pm (\sqrt{5}-1)\,\text{i}$.